# what is wrong with my jquery mobile data-icon?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, button, icons

I have a icon for my home button and based on what I know it should work but doesn't. Does anyone know why?

My code is below and I have included some of the header too.

```
    <link href="assets/css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div class="title"><h2>Howard Consulting and Investments</h2></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Home</a>
        <a href="#project" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="a">Projects</a>
        <a href="#event" data-role="button">Events</a>
        <a href="#oppertnity" data-role="button">Oppertunities</a>
        <a href="#contact" data-role="button">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: You would have to show some css, if you want to know why your css is not working...

Comment: hmm the only relevant one is on the second line

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Icon doesn't appear or what?

Comment: data icon should be like this one data-icon="home" not data-icon="arrow-r" if that is what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work for me.. See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cardinal27513/UzXsB/2/).

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>Howard Consulting and Investments</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Home</a>
        <a href="#project" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="a">Projects</a>
        <a href="#event" data-role="button">Events</a>
        <a href="#oppertnity" data-role="button">Oppertunities</a>
        <a href="#contact" data-role="button">Contact Us</a>

    </div>
</div>
```